# Avro epoch datetime to bq timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I want to load the data from Avro files stored in GCS to big query table.
Two fields in avro are having datetimc

I have Avro files with couple of fields out of which one field has Epoch time values having Long type.
For that field I want to load value in 'Timestamp' format while loading the Avro file data to Bigquery table using command line tool or console.
For example :
I have a column having value 1614004223589 and I want this value to be loaded as 2021-02-22 14:28:56 UTC using command line tool or console. First I created empty table in BQ and kept the datatype of the field as TIMESTAMP then using CLI loaded the data into BQ table. But instead of 2021-02-22 14:30:24 I am getting 1970-01-19 16:20:04.135924 UTC

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Unix format with second precision, however BQ requires it to be in milli-second or micro-second precision multiply the column by 1000 and then try to concert using function `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS` it will work.

You can try out following solution to achieve desired requirements.

**Step 1**: Load data to Bigquery in same format as available over source file.
**Step 2**: Create a View over recently table and apply Date transformations in that view, going further always refer View for data.

***Alternate solution***:-
**Step 1**: Load data to Bigquery in same format as available over GCS.
**Step 2**: Create a function for Date transformation and apply function on Unix format date, before you call data.

Comment: Actually I want to load the data directly to BQ tables without any hop. Because my table is partition and the partition is based on the TIMESTAMP field.

Comment: Then can you try multiplying your source value by 1000, after that it will be transformed to timestamp while loading.

Comment: Vibhor, the solution by multiplying value with 1000 worked thanks. But since it has time along with date is it possible to extract Year, Month, Day while loading into BQ and use them as a partition columns?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you only want to load DATE part, not timestamp ?

Comment: No, I want to load both date & time.

Comment: Than it will be straight forward to extract timestamp from 'EXTRACT' function over Bigquery once you have data over BigQuery.

Comment: I don't want to do any transformation after loading data into BigQuery Table. Once the data will be loaded into BQ table it should be loaded into partition.